# for loop reassigning completely unrelated variable

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int xx = 8;
int Num[xx];
int Num9, Num10, Num11;
int StudentID;
int i;
int m = 0;
int j = 3;
int k = 6;
const int NUM_STUDENTS = 3;
const int NUM_DATA = 4;
int scores[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_DATA] =
{{2046, 97, 79, 86},
 {7634, 91, 78, 79},
 {8120, 73, 77, 82}};

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   Num[m]=scores[i][1] * 0.3;
    m++;
}

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    Num[j]=scores[i][2] * 0.3;
    j++;
}

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  Num[k]=scores[i][3] * 0.4;
    k++;
}

Num9=Num[0]+Num[3]+Num[6];
Num10=Num[1]+Num[4]+Num[7];
Num11=Num[2]+Num[5]+Num[8];
```

This is the code at hand. This block:

```
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
   Num[k]=scores[i][3] * 0.4;
    k++;
 }
```

Somehow changes the value for scores[0][0] to 32 from 2046. The equation seems to be doing it as when I block it off scores resets to 2046. Why would that be?
I've tried re-writing the equation there and nothing happens either.

Comment: `Num` is 8 ints and the end of the code accesses 9 elements. Looks like something's off.

Comment: Not the reason on, on the third cycle of the for loop changes it to 32.

Comment: The reason for this problem is that `N[2]` and `score[0][0]` have the same memory location.

Comment: I got it. const int xx needed to be 9 not 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes with `const int xx = 8;`

You declare `int Num[xx];` which is an array of 8 integers.

Next, in your 3rd loop, you try to access `Num[8]` which is the 9th position in the array, thus you are effectively writing the memory placed after `Num[7]` which happens to be `scores[0][0]`

For fun, you can try `Num[10] = 1234` and you can see `scores[0][2]` becomes 1234 as well.